# Where is the file selection widget in Drupal code?

Tags: 7

If a content type has an image field then when the user creates new content, he is present with an image section on the form with a widget to "Browse" for a file.  Clicking it provides a pop-up window standard dialog box for selecting a file.  I would like to examine how this works to use it in a custom module, but cannot locate the code in the core modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog box is a feature of your browser. The server sends HTML code looking something like

```
<input type="file">
```

Most browsers render this by providing a text input field and a *Browse* button.

Comment: I have searched through core trying to find an instance of this call in association with the Browse button mentioned in my question to confirm how to incorporate it into a form without success. I have asked a new question seeking an answer. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

The code to generate a field upload form element is in [`theme_file()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_file/7). The code is very simple because all it does is to output an [HTML file select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select) form element. As explained in other answers, the files browsing dialog is provided by the web browser and, most of the time, re-uses the operating system native one.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing client side and server side. The code you are seeking is internal to the browser (the client); it is not within Drupal (the server).